# Upgrading from React Native .67.5 to .68.6 - Android Bundle Release failing Java 1.8 vs 1.11

Tags: java, android, react-native, azure-devops

I've upgraded using the React Native Upgrade Helper - Android app is building locally, but failing in pipeline with with cd android
./gradlew bundleRelease

I have 1.11 java installed locally. Android Studio gradle also pointed to 1.11

````
Note: /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/codegen/generator/SchemaJsonParser.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:jar

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/runner/work/1/s/android/app/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
  > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
    You can try some of the following options:
      - changing the IDE settings.
      - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
      - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.```
````

Comment: Is JAVA_HOME  pointing correctly ? Maybe you have several versions installed ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware?  ```me@MYMAC~ % echo $JAVA_HOME 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strictly a Azure Pipeline Issue.

There is a Java tool installer plugin that wasnt being leveraged.

Added YAML as follows:

```
- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use Java 11'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 11
    jdkArchitectureOption: x64
    jdkSourceOption: PreInstalled
```